# Loading continues even though all data has already been fetched

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, opera

Opera keeps loading on my page, it shows something like 64/64 elements loaded or 44/44. How do I find out what makes it load so long? This problem only occurs in Opera, Chrome, Ie and FF just finish loading.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to see if it is indeed a pending network request (for an image resource, or css, etc) is to install Fiddler debugging proxy. After starting the Fiddler tool and navigating with your browser your website you'll see what network requests are issued and their respective status (pending, completed, error, etc)... Check for a "pending" network request...

Comment: Fiddler does not intercept opera calls. It works with Chrome, but that does not help me.

Comment: You can set Opera to use Fiddler as a proxy. Go to opera settings you'll find it somewhere. Th proxy address will be: http://127.0.0.1:8888 or http://yourlocalip:8888

Comment: I cannot find the status statement. Are you referring to 404, 200, 403 etc? What would be pending then?